# Adding ids for classes

Tags: jquery

I would like to get all the elements of a certain class and add sequential ids to them and also put them in an array.
Here is what i have so far.

```
(function(){
    for(var i = 1; i<$(".slideshow").length; i++){
        $(".slideshow").attr("id", "slides-" + i + "")
    }
});
```

What happens is it sets the id of all the .slideshow classes at the same time, making them all equal to the last (actually second to last, a bug to be worked out later)

How do i set the id of each individual class? If i do the each loop:

```
$(".slideshow").each(function(){
    for(var i = 1; i<$(".slideshow").length; i++){
        $(".slideshow").attr("id", "slides-" + i + "")
    }
});
```

How do i use "this" maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the callback function passed into [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) takes two params: first, the index of element in the collection, second, the element itself, you can write it like this:

```
$(".slideshow").each(function(i, el){
    el.id = 'slides-' + i;
});
```

As `id` attribute is commonly supported, there's no need using `$(el).attr('id', ...)` construct here.

Note that indexing of slides starts from 0 here. If you want to do it like in the original code (1-based), use this:

```
    el.id = 'slides-' + (i + 1);
```

Parenthesis around `i + 1` sub-expression are crucial, as these should be added, not concatenated.

Without parens, the expression will be processed as `('slides' + i) + 1`. The first `+` sign is placed between String and Number, thus will be treated as a concatenation operator, giving you a `String` in return. So the next `+` becomes a concat op too - giving you `'slides-91'` (and not the expected `'slides-10'`) when `i` is 9, for example.

If you need an array as a result, just use [**.toArray()**](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) method of jQuery object:

```
var slideShowNodes = $(".slideshow").each(function(i, el){
    el.id = 'slides-' + i;
}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Increments the ID, and puts all the elements in an array-like nodeList ?

```
var arr = $(".slideshow").prop('id',function(i) {
    return "slides-" + i;
}).get();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8dJM/2/)